# How do I set a date value in a specific format in PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below is my PL SQL block of code , I want to store a date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD

```
set serveroutput on;
declare

student_dob         DATE := TO_DATE('1988-07-05','YYYY-MM-DD');


begin 

   dbms_output.put_line ('student_dob  --> ' || student_dob);

end ;
```

It gives me the output as below

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

student_dob  --> 05-07-88
```

I can understand that the output is returned based on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT , but how do i set the variable student_dob    with the date format i want ?

Is it possible only by updating the  NLS_DATE_FORMAT inside   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS  ? Or is there any other option available in pl sql block of code itself?

```
expected date value for student_dob    --> 1988-07-05
```

Comment: If you're storing it in a `DATE` variable/column then it doesn't *have* a format. Don't confuse string representations (which you control when you convert from/to strings) with the *data* which is just the fundamental information about a specific point in time.

Comment: `dbms_output.put_line()` does not mean **store**! If you really plan to **store** the date as string - don't do that! Use proper `DATE` values, **never** store date/time values as string.

Answer (score 1):

Either set format explicitly with `TO_CHAR()`:

```
TO_CHAR(student_dob, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or alter your session:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''YYYY-MM-DD''';
```

or set NLS-Parameter directly

```
DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS('NLS_DATE_FORMAT', '"YYYY-MM-DD"');
```

or set it in your client before you connect to Oracle. This can be done for example with Environment Variables:

```
SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD"
```

or in your Registry (applies only for Windows, of course), etc.

Don't even think about running `UPDATE NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS SET VALUE = ... WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';`

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use `TO_CHAR` to do the reverse of taking your date and rendering it in a specific string format:

```sql
dbms_output.put_line ('student_dob  --> ' ||
    TO_CHAR(student_dob, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```